# "Call to undefined function" in PHP-FPM during second request in my own PHP extension

Tags: php, php-extension

I am writing a PHP extension. Inside it I have my own function which only writes one string argument passed to this function. I am using Apache 2.4 and PHP-FPM with PHP 5.4.8. In PHP-FPM configuration I have only one process to handle PHP requests.

I have a simple example with only this one function. With the first request everything seems fine but the second request returns a "Call to undefined function" fatal error.

Is there some special way to write extensions for PHP-FPM or could it be a bug in PHP?

EDIT:

Code - config.m4:

```
dnl $Id$
dnl config.m4 for extension phpExtension

PHP_ARG_ENABLE(phpExtension, whether to enable phpExtension support,
[  --enable-phpextension           Enable phpExtension support])

if test "$PHP_PHPEXTENSION" != "no"; then

    PHP_REQUIRE_CXX()

    PHP_NEW_EXTENSION(phpExtension, phpExtension.cpp, $ext_shared)

    PHP_SUBST(PHPEXTENSION_SHARED_LIBADD)

    PHP_ADD_LIBRARY(stdc++, 1, PHPEXTENSION_SHARED_LIBADD)
fi
```

phpExtension.h:

```
#ifndef PHP_PHPEXTENSION_H
#define PHP_PHPEXTENSION_H

extern zend_module_entry phpExtension_module_entry;
#define phpext_phpExtension_ptr &phpExtension_module_entry

#ifdef PHP_WIN32
#   define PHP_PHPEXTENSION_API __declspec(dllexport)
#elif defined(__GNUC__) && __GNUC__ >= 4
#   define PHP_PHPEXTENSION_API __attribute__ ((visibility("default")))
#else
#   define PHP_PHPEXTENSION_API
#endif

#ifdef ZTS
#include "TSRM.h"
#endif

PHP_MINIT_FUNCTION(phpExtension);
PHP_MSHUTDOWN_FUNCTION(phpExtension);
PHP_RINIT_FUNCTION(phpExtension);
PHP_RSHUTDOWN_FUNCTION(phpExtension);
PHP_MINFO_FUNCTION(phpExtension);

PHP_FUNCTION(phpExtensionTest);

#ifdef ZTS
#define phpExtension_G(v) TSRMG(phpExtension_globals_id, zend_phpExtension_globals *, v)
#else
#define phpExtension_G(v) (phpExtension_globals.v)
#endif

ZEND_BEGIN_MODULE_GLOBALS(phpExtension)
ZEND_END_MODULE_GLOBALS(phpExtension)

static PHP_GINIT_FUNCTION(phpExtension);
static PHP_GSHUTDOWN_FUNCTION(phpExtension);

static int php_phpExtension_post_deactivate();

#endif  /* PHP_PHPEXTENSION_H */
```

phpExtension.cpp:

```
#ifdef HAVE_CONFIG_H
#include "config.h"
#endif

#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <utility>
#include <string>

extern "C"
{
#include <ctype.h> //tolower
#include <stdio.h>

#include "php.h"
#include "php_ini.h"
#include "ext/standard/info.h"
#include "zend_vm_opcodes.h"
#include "zend_compile.h"
#include "zend_hash.h"
#include "zend_operators.h"
#include "zend_exceptions.h"
#include "php_phpExtension.h"
#include "zend_API.h"
#include "SAPI.h"
#include "zend_llist.h"
#include "zend.h"
#include "php_syslog.h"
#include <syslog.h>
}

using namespace std;

ZEND_DLEXPORT zend_function_entry phpExtension_functions[] =
{
    PHP_FE(phpExtensionTest, NULL)
    PHP_FE_END /* Must be the last line in phpExtension_functions[] */
};

ZEND_DECLARE_MODULE_GLOBALS(phpExtension)

zend_module_entry phpExtension_module_entry =
{
#if ZEND_MODULE_API_NO >= 20010901
    STANDARD_MODULE_HEADER,
#endif
    "phpExtension",
    phpExtension_functions,
    PHP_MINIT(phpExtension),
    PHP_MSHUTDOWN(phpExtension),
    PHP_RINIT(phpExtension),
    PHP_RSHUTDOWN(phpExtension),
    PHP_MINFO(phpExtension),
#if ZEND_MODULE_API_NO >= 20010901
    "0.1", /* TODO Replace with version number for your extension */
#endif
    PHP_MODULE_GLOBALS(phpExtension),
    PHP_GINIT(phpExtension),
    PHP_GSHUTDOWN(phpExtension),
    php_phpExtension_post_deactivate,
    STANDARD_MODULE_PROPERTIES_EX
};

extern "C"
{
    #ifdef COMPILE_DL_PHPEXTENSION
    ZEND_GET_MODULE(phpExtension)
#endif
}

/**
 * Initializes global parameters
 */
static PHP_GINIT_FUNCTION(phpExtension)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "phpExtension ginit\n");
    fflush(stderr);
}

static PHP_GSHUTDOWN_FUNCTION(phpExtension)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "phpExtension gshutdown\n");
    fflush(stderr);
}

static int php_phpExtension_post_deactivate()
{
    fprintf(stderr, "phpExtension php_phpExtension_post_deactivate\n");
    fflush(stderr);

    return SUCCESS;
}

PHP_MSHUTDOWN_FUNCTION(phpExtension)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "phpExtension mshutdown\n");
    fflush(stderr);

    return SUCCESS;
}

PHP_RINIT_FUNCTION(phpExtension)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "phpExtension rinit\n");
    fflush(stderr);

    return SUCCESS;
}

PHP_RSHUTDOWN_FUNCTION(phpExtension)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "phpExtension rshutdown\n");
    fflush(stderr);

    return SUCCESS;
}

PHP_MINFO_FUNCTION(phpExtension)
{
    php_info_print_table_start();
    php_info_print_table_header(2, "phpExtension support", "enabled");
    php_info_print_table_end();
}

PHP_FUNCTION(phpExtensionTest)
{
    int len;
    char *str;

    if (zend_parse_parameters(ZEND_NUM_ARGS() TSRMLS_CC, "s", &str, &len) == FAILURE)
    {
        RETURN_NULL();
    }

    php_printf("passed string: %s\n", str);

    RETURN_NULL();
}

PHP_MINIT_FUNCTION(phpExtension)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "phpExtension SAPI: %s %s\n", sapi_module.name, sapi_module.pretty_name);
    fflush(stderr);

    return SUCCESS;
}
```

and script.php:

```
<?php

phpExtensionTest("Test");
```

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: Which function is undefined?

Comment: Maybe need load your extasion using dl() http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.dl.php

Comment: I added code example.

@Pekka웃: My, which is defined in my extension